# Difference between Character.isLowerCase(myChar) and 'a'<=myChar && 'z'>=myChar

Tags: java, utf-8

I'm writing a simple parser to count the number of lowercase letters in a big text file. I use **Character.isLowerCase(myChar)** to the characters. The result I got on Java 6 is smaller than that on Java 8.

So why does this happen? Also how can we define "lowercase letters"? Only English lowercase letters?

To clarify:

1. The difference in the results should be because of the different Java versions(Java 8 and Java 6).
2. I'm asking two questions. First, **Character.isLowerCase(myChar)** on different Java versions. Second, difference between Character.isLowerCase(myChar) and 'a'<=myChar && 'z'>=myChar.

Comment: _The result I got on Oracle JDK is smaller than that on OpenJDK_ can you please elaborate

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `Character.isLowerCase`?

Comment: áéíóú and other similar characters.

Comment: How you define lowercase is up to you... it depends on what problem you're trying to solve. I'm still trying to figure out what your question  is really asking, the title implies that there is a difference between `Character.isLowerCase(myChar)` and `'a' <= myChar && 'z'>=myChar`, but then your description implies the difference was actually between different JDKs...

Comment: And just to be clear, as others have implied, there **is** a difference between `Character.isLowerCase(myChar)` and `'a' <= myChar && 'z'>=myChar`. The former takes into consideration all unicode characters that it considers to be lowercase, and the latter explicitly only counts the lowercase english characters.

Answer (score 2):

Well reading the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase%28char%29) this tells me that it checks if it is lower case it `returns true else returns false`

The code you have i.e `a <= myChar && 'z'>= myChar` is evaluating to the same thing `IF IT WAS ONLY ASCII` given that:

In `ascii` `a = 97` and `z= 122`.

The `isLower` function also returns lowercase unicode.

Answer (score 2):

There is 1402 characters which are considered lower case.

```
int count = 0;
for(char ch = Character.MIN_VALUE; ch < Character.MAX_VALUE;ch++)
    if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
        count++;
System.out.println("Lower case is " + count);
```